# Notification Wont Show up

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my app, when I send a message I do not get a notification that message was sent on another account. I'm new to this so not sure what I am doing wrong. I know there can be an issue on how the data is loaded or something like that but I'm not sure what the issue is. I have tried other solutions on that I've found but nothing seems to work for me. Any help would be appreciated.UPDATE: I am able to send a message from firebase to my phone and notification pops up. My only issues now is how to get this working between two users.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("text");
            String username = remoteMessage.getData().get("username");
            String uid = remoteMessage.getData().get("uid");
            String fcmToken = remoteMessage.getData().get("fcm_token");

            // Don't show notification if chat activity is open.
            if (!FirebaseChatMainApp.isChatActivityOpen()) {
                sendNotification(title,
                        message,
                        username,
                        uid,
                        fcmToken);
                Log.i("MESSAGE","Goes here");

            } else {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new PushNotificationEvent(title,
                        message,
                        username,
                        uid,
                        fcmToken));
                Log.i("MESSAGE","Goes here");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String title,
                                  String message,
                                  String receiver,
                                  String receiverUid,
                                  String firebaseToken) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.ARG_RECEIVER, receiver);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.ARG_RECEIVER_UID, receiverUid);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.ARG_FIREBASE_TOKEN, firebaseToken);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_messaging)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.handleIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try debug. And include the crash log in the question

Comment: Sorry for the late response, my issues is that the code runs fine, no crashes. Thats why I cant figure out why it isnt showing up

Comment: Do you check your Firebase Notifications on Firebase website? Is it send to your phone?

Comment: Hi, so I am able to send a message from firebase and i receive the notification, my only issues now is getting the notifications between uses.